# One method for changing one of the properties

Tags: c#, hash-map, enum, properties

I have a few resources set in my class – coins, diamonds, hearts, enum of these resources names, and method for increasing specified resource. I want to make single "Increase" method for all resources that wouldn't have switch statement. Sort of single-line not overloaded "generic" method independently on which property to increase. Below is the best what I achieved so far. Please advice on best approach to be taken for the described Increase method.

```
public enum ResourceType { Coins, Diamond, Hearts };

private static int Coins { get { return resourceBox[ResourceType.Coins]; } }
private static int Diamonds { get { return resourceBox[ResourceType.Diamonds]; } }
private static int Hearts { get { return resourceBox[ResourceType.Hearts]; } }
private static Dictionary<ResourceType, int> resourceBox = new Dictionary<ResourceType, int>();

private void Init()
{
    resourceBox.Add(ResourceType.Coins, 0);
    resourceBox.Add(ResourceType.Diamond, 0);
    resourceBox.Add(ResourceType.Hearts, 0);
}

public static void Increase(ResourceType _res, int _income)
{
resourceBox[_res] += _income;
}
```

However this leads to situation where Dictionary is a primary resource storage, which may not be desired in future.
I wonder what could be another (not obligatory dictionary) way to create Increase method as described above.

Comment: Could add the entire class definition? It's hard to comment on that small piece of code.

Comment: Well, that's basically almost it, except for a few methods:

`code`
public class Resources 
{}
`/code`

Comment: `code
public static void Spend(ResourceType _res, decimal _price) 
    {
        switch (_res)
        {
            case ResourceType.Coins:
                Coins -= _price;
                break;
            case ResourceType.Diamond:
                Diamonds -= _price;
                break;
            case ResourceType.Hearts:
                Hearts -= _price;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (OnResourceChanged != null)
            OnResourceChanged(_res, _price);
    }`

Comment: And a few similar methods with ugly switches.

Comment: Using a Dictionary is just an implementation detail which isn't exposed, if the time came to change it, you could do so without changing any other code that uses the Increase function. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I find there is nothing wrong with using a dictionary here. What I'm worried about are those properties:

> ```
> private static int Coins { get { return resourceBox[ResourceType.Coins]; } }
> private static int Diamonds { get { return resourceBox[ResourceType.Diamonds]; } }
> private static int Hearts { get { return resourceBox[ResourceType.Hearts]; } }
> ```

Why do you need them? They are not only `static` but also `private`. If you cannot access them from *the outside* how are you going to use them?

You didn't include the complete class definition but just a small snippet so it's hard to give you more feedback.

Comment: Static method **Increase** is used outside of this class, so I had to change properties to static as well in order for Increase to have access to them.
Sorry, can't show the whole class because of characters limitations. The main responsibility of **Resources** class is storing and changing those private properties.

Comment: @Madcode _can't show the whole class because of characters limitations_ ;-) this means there is so much wrong with this class if it doesn't even fit into a question. You really need to split it up into smaller pieces.

Comment: Removed spaces, now it's ok) Don't mind decimals and int types. Really now properties don't need to be static as they are not called from **Increase** method directly.
Here is snippet of how class looked before dictionary approach: 
`public static void Spend(ResourceType _res, decimal _price) 
switch (_res)
case ResourceType.Coins:
Coins -= _price;
break;
case ResourceType.Diamond:
Diamonds -= _price;
break;
case ResourceType.Hearts:
Hearts -= _price;
break;
default:
break;}`
And few other methods of same repetitive structure. So I wanted to avoid this bulk switches.

Comment: @Madcode we on Code Review have a character limit of 65535 characters.